# transform the values of one axis to its log

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to transform the scales on y-axis to the log values. For example, if one of the numbers on y is 0.01, I want to get -2 (which is log(0.01)). How should I do this in matplotlib (or any other library)?!

Thanks,

Comment: `plt.yscale('log')`?

Comment: @JohanC I already worked with this. But it transforms 0.01 to 10^(-2)!! Or maybe I couldn't work with that! (don't know!)

Comment: @JohanC Actually I'm working with sns.distplot (sns is the abbreviation of seaborn) and I want to transform the scales of y-axis to its log value!   plt.plot(x,np.log10(y)) doesn't work for my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `plt.yscale('log')` there will be few y-ticks visible that have a nice number as log. You can change the "formatter" to a function that only shows the exponent.  Also note that in the latest seaborn version `distplot` has been replaced by `histplot(..., kde=True)` or `kdeplot(...)`.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatterExponent
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(10, 1000).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
ax = sns.histplot(x, kde=True, stat='density', color='purple')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LogFormatterExponent(base=10.0, labelOnlyBase=True))
ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel() + ' (exponent)')
ax.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: histplot with LogFormatterExponent]

Comment: thanks a lot!... This is exactly what I'm looking for....